# Передвижение Canvas элемента

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, wpf-canvas

Я прописал логику движения элемента Canvas, но она не работает, могли бы помочь

```
<Grid> 
    <Image Source="E:\programming\BallistasWar\BallistasWar\imgs\GameBack.png" Stretch="Fill"/> 

    <Canvas KeyDown="MainBallista_KeyDown"> 
        <Image x:Name="MainBallista" Source="E:\programming\BallistasWar\BallistasWar\imgs\Ballista1.png" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Left="1199" Canvas.Top="640" Height="260" Width="308"/> 
    </Canvas> 
</Grid>
```

АБО

```
public partial class Game : Window 
{ 
    public Game() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
    } 

    private void MainBallista_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
    { 
        if(e.Key == Key.Space)  
        { 
            Canvas.SetLeft(MainBallista, Canvas.GetLeft(MainBallista) + 100.0); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: да, в loaded прописал функцию, которая на canvas клеит фокус, потом в <> файла ещё добавить  focusable = "True"