# C# WPF между окнами

Tags: c#, wpf

Как правильно создать окно, чтобы я могу к нему обращаться из других окон и классов?

А то сделал так

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
    public static Game game = new Game();
}
```

но в другом классе и окне использовать не могу.

прошу пожалуйста дать прямое решение

Comment: Учить MVVM, пример здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222168/373567

Comment: А вообще я отвечал вам [на прошлый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1508394/373567), но вы так и не отреагировали на ответ совершенно никак, пришлось его удалить как бесполезный. Зачем тогда вы задаете вопросы, если даже не смотрите ответы?

Comment: возможно я нашел сам ответ и забил, извиняюсь